# How to retrive specific data from a SQL database with JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I've created a SQL-database containing three tables: Student, Course, Studies. I have no problem adding and retrieving information from/to student and course but when I try to do the same with Studies I get som problems. I've narrowed it down to the segment shown below. The problem is that I can add a student that does not exist in the Studies-table (but does exist in the Student & course tables) without a problem. But if I already have a student that's in the studies table and I wan't to add another entry (i.e. a student who studies more then one course) I get nothing. I've tried bypassing it with numerous loops and methods outside the codesegment, but nothing works. I'm pretty sure I'm close to the answer but I need help to get to the end. Any help is appreciated.

```
public void saveStudies() throws SQLException {

    String checkSql = "select count(*) as count from studies where spnr=?";
    PreparedStatement checkStmt = con.prepareStatement(checkSql);

    String insertSql = "insert into studies (spnr, cid) values (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement insertStmt = con.prepareStatement(insertSql);

    for(Studies studies: studiess) {
        int spnr = studies.getSpnr();
        int cid = studies.getCid();

        checkStmt.setInt(1, spnr);

        ResultSet checkResult = checkStmt.executeQuery();
        checkResult.next();

        int count = checkResult.getInt(1);

        if(count == 0) {

            System.out.println("Inserting student with pnr: " + spnr + " into course with cid: " + cid);

            insertStmt.setInt(1, spnr);
            insertStmt.setInt(2, cid);

            insertStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("A message containing information that says that the student and or course does not exist in the database");
        }

    }

    insertStmt.close();
    checkStmt.close();
}
```

Comment: you realize that isn't transactionally safe, right? someone could insert something inbetween when you check the count and when you do the insert.

Comment: Look at your select query again. Describe to us in words what it is actually counting.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy - Considering the scope and the limitations of the application, that issue will not be a problem.

Comment: @GordThompson - Well, it's creating a new column called "count" which stores the amount of times a specifik student id (called spnr) appears in the studies table.

Comment: Right, and you've said that you can add a student the first time (hint: when `count == 0` is `true`) but you cannot add the same student a second time. Can you see why that might be?

Comment: Yes, it's cause the count will now not be 0, it will be for this example 1. I've tried playing with the arguments in the for-loop by putting count not equal 0, having the count bigger/smaller etc. But nothing seems to work. Mostly because of the checkResult.next() line. But if I remove that and tweak the code a little I can make it so that I can add a student multiple times, but then I can not add a totaly new student to the table.

Comment: ...but if you want to be able to add a student more than once then why are you checking whether or not they are in the "studies" table at all? In other words, what is the intended purpose of checking the "studies" table before inserting the new row for a given student?

Comment: I'm thinking that I need to check weather or not the student exists in the database (other tables). I can not add a student which does not exist, therefore I check if the student exists in order to add student. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way? I mean, if I get rid of the for-loop and just write make the inserts statement, what will prevent me from writing a ID which does not exsist?

Comment: If you want to check that the student exists in some other table (e.g., the "students" table) then your select query should be checking that table, not the "studies" table.

Comment: Hmm, that is true. Let me try some stuff out and see where I land.

Answer (score 0):

As statet below I was checking the wrong table. The solution is to check the other two tables (Student and Course) in order to find out weather or not I can add some entry to the studies table (which requires one student and one course).